# HTML button- when hold the button it will repeat the action

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to HTML and I'm working on a project that is required to use a button when you pressed and hold it, it would repeat the same action. This is the code I got sofar but did not work.

```
    !DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Button</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button id = "forward" accesskey="o" onmousedown="display(1)" onmouseup="stop()">forward</button>


    <script>

    function stop(){
        console.log(" ")
    }
    function display(value){
        if (value == 1){
            console.log("left");}}
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need is `setInterval` and `clearInterval`.

## Code

```js
var wrapper = document.getElementById('counter');
  var counter;
  var count = 0;
  
  function start() {
    counter = setInterval(function() {
      wrapper.innerHTML = count;
      count++;
    }, 500);
  }
  function end() {
    clearInterval(counter)
  }
```

```html
<button onmousedown="start()" onmouseup="end()">Click and hold</button>
<p id="counter"></p>
```

## Explanation

If you're not familiar with `setInterval` and `clearInterval`, they are similar to `setTimeout`. You can assign `setInterval` to a variable that you can pass to `clearInterval` later to stop it. What this does is it puts the code you pass into it on a different stack, so your other code can continue to execute, such as an `onmouseup` event that can clear it.

## Practice

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp

## Documentation

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval

Comment: I tried the same method but it keep repeat action when I clicked and not even held it. I also included clearInterval in onmouseup but didn't work.

Comment: If you move your mouse off the button when you release it, that will happen. You'll probably want to attach the `onmouseup` event listener to a parent element, perhaps the `body` tag.

Comment: When you release the mouse, the `onmouseup` event is triggered, even if there is nothing listening for it, this is why you'd want to put it on parent element that "wraps" around your entire page, in this case, the `body` element is the best place to listen for the `onmouseup` event.

Comment: I finally did it with onmouseup and onmousedown. However, I tried to work on it on project that post a command to a cloud

var counter;
        
        function end() {
            clearInterval(counter)
        }

        function display(value) {
            if (value == 1) {

                counter = setInterval(function () {
                    paramStr = "f";
                }, 200);
            }
            var requestURL = "https://api.particle.io/v1/devices/deviceID/Car/";
            $.post(requestURL, { params: paramStr, access_token: accessToken });
        }

Answer (score 1):

Update on @AnonymousSB answer for touch support:

```
//repeat on btn hold
let btnHoldCounter;
["mousedown", "touchstart"].forEach(event => {
    back_btn.addEventListener(event, () => {
        btnHoldCounter= setInterval(
             %ExecuteMe%
        , 200);
    });
});
["mouseup", "touchend"].forEach(event => {
    back_btn.addEventListener(event, () => {
        clearInterval(btnHoldCounter);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your context (synchronize/asynchronize processing). You can use setInterval function or “self-calling” function (recursion) or combine both. But make sure that you have to process to clear it when it is not used anymore. If not, it will effect to your app performance.

For setInterval, it will run asynchronize and multi your actions can process at the same time. So, you need to process to keep your data always true. This is the most important.

For “self-calling” function, you can process repeat action in synchronize.

More details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval

https://javascript.info/recursion

Below is simple example about using setInterval function. Hope that help.

```
var repeatId; // Keep ID value to we clear repeating.
var count = 0; // Count to see the number of times of repeating

function display(value){
        console.log("Start...");

    // Initialize repeating and keep ID value to use when we want to clear repeating
    repeatId = setInterval(
      // This function will be invoked after a period time
        function() {
        console.log("Holding" + (++count) + ", your value: " + value);
        }, 
      1000 // Repeat after 1 second.
    );
}

function stop(){
    clearInterval(repeatId);// Clear repeating
    count = 0;
    console.log("Stop");
}
```