# I want to make a button that you can hold down to make a variable go up repeatadly BUT

Tags: javascript, html

i want you to have to hold the button down for a second for it to start...
I've tried a couple of things like

```
function startHold1() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    startHold1A = setInterval(func1(), 250) }, 1000)
}

function endHold1() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    clearInterval(startHold1A, 950)
  })
}
```

func1 basically adds 1 to a variable and displays it on the screen also i have a button that initiates startHold1 onmousedown and endHold1 onmouseup
I'm a super noob at code please help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML button- when hold the button it will repeat the action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347492/html-button-when-hold-the-button-it-will-repeat-the-action)

Comment: ` setInterval(func1(), 250)` => ` setInterval(func1, 250)` (no `()` after `func`), see the linked question's answers.

Answer (score -3):

```js
var setint  = '';
$(document).ready(function() {
var val = 0;
$('#hold').on('mousedown',function (e) {
   clearInterval(setint);
   val = 0;
   setint = setInterval(function () {
       $("#putdata").val(++val);
        console.log("mousehold");
   },50);
});
$('#hold').on("mouseleave mouseup", function () {
   val = 0;
   $("#putdata").val(val);
   clearInterval(setint);
});
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="putdata" />
<input type="button" value="mouse-hold" id="hold" />
</body>
<html>
```

Comment: adding jquery isn't always the best answer to a javascript question.

Comment: yes.. adding jquery isnt always the best answer.. but it is an answer.  and it answers the question at hand...

Last time i checked jquery is javascript. 
feel free to add alternative answers.